# how to replace pandas first two value in a list with zero and other values replace with image hight and width?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

expertise;
I am working on pandas data frame where I want to replace some values in columns which are basically containing the list of lists and its have both `nan` values in some rows and some of them contain Bounding Box coordinates.
I am attaching a sample of the data frame please have a look [DataFrame](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SSQCEzFr1gZo8uHvI2CxU654XXyM8lfI/view?usp=sharing).

The data frame is look like this:

```
img_id                                   BB                                      class                                         w     h
001   [[nan, nan, nan, nan], [nan, nan, nan, nan], [nan, nan, nan, nan]]        ['No finding', 'No finding', 'No finding']     2336      2836
```

I want to fill the first two `nan` on row where we have `no finding` with `0` and fill the remaining two `nan` with `hight` and `width` values. I showed in a dummy painted picture. How to do I am not an expert in pandas but know simple operations.

I want to fill all the lists in the list to fill like this

```
[[0, 0, 2336, 2836], [0, 0, 2336, 2836], [0, 0, 2336, 2836]]
```

Thanks
[image: dummy image]

Comment: Can you share more sample data (not in image), and what is expected exactly ?

Comment: did you check the link where I uploaded sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go :

*Make sure to `import re` module first.

```
import re

for _ in range(0, 3):

    #Repalce two ocurenaces of nan to zeros.
    df['bboxes'] = df['bboxes'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('nan', '0',x ,2))

    #Repalce third ocurenace of nan with width data.
    df['bboxes'] = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub('nan', str(x['width']),  x['bboxes'], 1), axis=1)

    #Repalce forth ocurenace of nan with height data.
    df['bboxes'] = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub('nan', str(x['height']), x['bboxes'], 1), axis=1)
```

There is the output of `bboxes` columns for first two values as you described :

```
[[0, 0, 2336, 2836], [0, 0, 2336, 2836], [0, 0, 2336, 2836]]
[[0, 0, 1994, 2430], [0, 0, 1994, 2430], [0, 0, 1994, 2430]]
```

Comment: thanks, @ibraheem but I want to fill all the lists the same as you filled the first list?
actually, this task is for the detection of some thoric disease where I am validating my model on another dataset where this kind of data frame is needed.
So here I want to fill all the list of no finding rows as you fill the first one

Comment: [[0, 0, 2336, 2836], [0, 0, 2336, 2836], [0, 0, 2336, 2836]]

Comment: yeah exactly like this

Comment: Refer to my edited answer, please mark as answerd after you verify it :)

Comment: sure I will and Thanks
I was thinking about `for loop` as you update the answer but I have `4k+` row in `CSV` so it will work for all or just we can give the length of that row like this `len(bbox[i])`?

Comment: It will work for all as long as array length is the same.

Comment: thanks you so much you really reduce my work to a day I marked please upvote my question too :)

Comment: should I ask a simple question on the new question you can answer there and it will help to get some reputation score.
I will paste a link here

Comment: Would suggest to ask new question, to get variety of answers.

Comment: Here is the link to that question I know its easy but due to low knowledge of padas I don't know how to do: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bfjEa3RKcVExQICAXhcL97jTz_p0J2tE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you want to add [ ] only for replaced nan ?

Comment: nope read the question properly i explain it